# 8051 string comparison using assembly

Tags: string, assembly, compare, 8051

I need to compare a string which is saved in Code memory location of the 8051 starting from 200H with another three strings which are also saved in the Code memory location this time staring from 300H.

The three strings will be separated by a comma to indicate different words and a full-stop will be used at the end of the words stream to indicate end of stream.

For now I managed to save the string to be compared and the other three strings as follows:

[image]

How can I continue comparing string by string till I find a matching one?

Comment: You might find it useful to first write and test a small C program on your development machine which does this (explicitly, not using library functions) in order to fully plan out the algorithm, then manually translate it to 8051 assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use CJNE insttruction for comparison. First move the content to Acc and compare with the first string. If it does match, traverse to "," : delimiter of stored string.
One you reach delimiter, initialize  the compare string pointer.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The first (and perhaps not the last) step should be to calculate the length of the string variable.
In the example you give, this will suffice. In the general case, this step is a variable filter that reduces the search array. After that it is necessary to use the analysis on coincidence at first of the first characters, then the second, etc.

Comment: For implicit-length (0-terminated) strings, normally a normal `strcmp` would step through both strings at once, so you're done when you find a difference, or find a `0` in one of them.  (At worst that takes to the end of the shorter one, and potentially much earlier if they differ very early).  Calculating both lengths requires looping through both of them, and then if they're the same you're going to have to go through both of them again.  Unless 8051 has a really hard time with pointers / indexing, it's probably not worth the extra code and cycles to separately strlen them.

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all you need to put string terminator `\0` at the end of string
2. try this subroutine for string comparison [see here](https://github.com/syeedameen/mcs-51-subroutines/blob/master/src/srting/strcmp.asm)

```
org 0x0000

push 0x00     ; push first string base address 
push 0x02     

push 0x00 
push 0x03     ; push second string base address 

call strcmp   ; if string equal return 0 
pop acc 

cjne a, #0x00, not_Equal
                  ; both strings are equals 
not_Equal:
                  ; string are not Equals  




org 0x0200
db "Srting 1",0
org 0x0300
db "String 2",0 







;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------;
;  Program subrotutine to compare two strings terminate with '\0' character   ;
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------;
; SUBROUTINE DESCRIPTION                                                      ;
;                     1. push base addresses of both addresses of string      ; 
;                           push address of n                                 ;
;                           push address of m                                 ;                     
; RESOURCES                                                                   ;
;                      2. only use r0,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5 register                 ;
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------;

; PROCEDURE FOR STRING COMPARISION 


;   /*  String Comparision Function if stirng equal return 0 otherwise 
;       return difference between last two string
;   */
;int strcmp(char *m, char *n)
;{
;   while (*m != '\0' && *n != '\0')
;   {
;       if (*m == *n)
;       {
;           m++;
;           n++;
;       }
;       else 
;       {
;           return *m - *n;
;       }
;   }
;   return *m - *n;
;}
        
strcmp:
    pop 0x7f 
    pop 0x7e 
    
    pop acc             ; first string base address (m) 
    mov r1, a 
    pop acc
    mov r0,a  

    pop acc             ; second string base address (n)
    mov r3, a 
    pop acc
    mov r2,a  

    push 0x7e
    push 0x7f
    

repeat_strcmp:
    mov dpl, r0 
    mov dph, r1 
    movx a, @dptr
    mov r4, a           ; *m    r4 <-- character of first string 
    
    mov dpl, r2 
    mov dph, r3 
    movx a, @dptr
    mov r5, a           ; *n    r5 <-- character of second string 
    
    cjne a, #'\0', checkSecond_strcmp
        mov a, r4       ; if first string end return *m - *n 
        clr c           
        subb a, r5 
        pop 0x7f 
        pop 0x7e 
        push acc 
        push 0x7e 
        push 0x7f 
        ret 

checkSecond_strcmp:
    cjne a, #'\0', skip_strcmp
        mov a, r4       ; if second string end return *m - *n 
        clr c 
        subb a, r5 
        pop 0x7f 
        pop 0x7e 
        push acc 
        push 0x7e 
        push 0x7f 
        ret
    skip_strcmp:
    
    mov a, r4           
    clr c 
    subb a, r5          ; cmp both string character by subb (make sure carry is 0)
    jnz notEqual_strcmp
        mov dpl, r0     ; if equal increment m++, n++ and repeat_strcmp 
        mov dph, r1 
        inc dptr 
        mov r0, dpl 
        mov r1, dph 
        
        mov dpl, r2 
        mov dph, r3 
        inc dptr 
        mov r2, dpl 
        mov r3, dph 
        jmp repeat_strcmp
    notEqual_strcmp:    
    mov a, r4           ; else return *m - *n 
    clr c 
    subb a, r5 
    pop 0x7f 
    pop 0x7e 
    push acc 
    push 0x7e 
    push 0x7f 
    ret
```

I hope this is helpful